# datevec Matlab skips time 00:00:00

Tags: matlab, datetime, time, format

I have an array of timestamps, these are just three examples:

```
time_1 = '23/01/2013 00:47:00'
time_2 = '04/02/2013 00:00:00'
time_3 = '27/01/2013 03:31:00'
```

I want to use 'datevec' on these timestamps:

```
tVec_1 = datevec(datenum(time_1,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'));
tVec_2 = datevec(datenum(time_2,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'));
tVec_3 = datevec(datenum(time_3,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'));
```

for the tVec_1 and tVec_3  timestamp it works nicely, but it crashes for the tVec_2:

```
Error using dtstr2dtvecmx
Failed on converting date string to date number.

Error in datevec (line 117)
            y = dtstr2dtvecmx(t,icu_dtformat);
```

I suspect, that the problem comes from "zero time" which is not treated properly by my format 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS' (if I remove the last "HH:MM:SS" then it works).

Unfortunately, I could not find anything useful on matlab website.

Suggestions are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, it goes through fine for me. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: I cannot replicate this in R2015a. Edit your question to include which `version` of Matlab you're using. Also, please show the output of `datenum(time_2,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')`. And does `datevec(time_2,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')` work (the calls to `datenum` seem superfluous)?

Comment: Thanks you guys! It was my internal mistake, so I must remove this question. Thanks again!